# How can I show profile pictures of everyone who has liked my site (and not just pictures of my friends) via the facebook api?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-graph-api

I've looked at facepile but

> This plugin only displays friends
>   photos. If the user does not have
>   friends who have liked your page or
>   have connected to your site, no faces
>   will be shown.

How can I display all of profile pictures of every user who has liked my site, and not just the ones that I'm friends with?

Comment: Don't think you can - it's probably a privacy thing. Try http://developers.facebook.com/plugins/ social plugins.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you can not claim user_ids of people, who like your page using the API. There was a method once, but it has been removed for some reasons. See [Facebook Bug Tracker](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12880) fur this issue.

As you can read in the bug comments, the "members" connection will be revised by FB, and hopefully be back soon. In case this is working again, you can fetch member_ids via API, and use the ids to show profiles with url like this: https://graph.facebook.com//picture